# Elegant way to increment x if x < 0 and decrement x if x > 0 in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a value that is between -5 and 5 and I need to drift it toward 0 in increments of 1. Is there an elegant way to do this without resorting to if and elif statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x += (x < 0) * 2 - 1
```

That should do it. Of course it's far too clever and nobody will understand it, you're much better off using an `if` statement.

This works because `(x < 0)` creates a boolean result, and booleans can substitute for integers with False=0 and True=1.

If you need to handle the case where x=0 by not changing at all it's a simple modification:

```
x += (x < 0) * 2 - (x != 0)
```

If you're not actually trying to avoid `if` altogether then the Pythonic way would be:

```
x += 1 if x < 0 else -1
```

Comment: You could also use `x += -1**(x>0)`

Comment: @DavidFaber this is StackOverflow, not CodeGolf.

Answer (score 3):

This should be good enough:

```
x += 1 if x < 0 else -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have a signum function, but has `copysign` instead, which is the next best thing:

```
import math
math.copysign(abs(x)-1, x)
```